# How should I pass an array from iOS to PHP to MySQL for proper storage (and back)?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, arrays

I know this is a loaded question, but I think what I'm doing right now is probably the wrong way to go about things, so I'd like some input as to what is best practice.

Currently I have an array of actors. Let's say `NSArray *actors` in Objective-C. I want to pass this up to my PHP page for storage.

Right now I pass this up on `HTTP POST` by turning the array into a string such as this:

```
&actors=Joe Allen*Dave Smith*Mary Johnson*Alice Burg?movietitle=Runner
```

When it gets to PHP I'm then passing it to MySQL via a Stored Procedure call like this:

```
CALL Add_Movie(movietitle, actors);
```

And then in my sproc is where I 'explode' the actors by `*` to save them in the correct table. I do the reverse to get the actors back. It's gotten even trickier for me when I've wanted to separate first/last names.

Anyway, this seems really hacky to me. What's best practice for an array transfer over HTTP to SQL storage and back?

Comment: JSON is the best. JSON is same as string but can be easily converted to array both ways. You need encode json in your HTTP

Comment: Star delimited is a rather unorthodox format. You probably want to POST a JSON document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pick an established serialization format, don't try to roll your own.

   - Established formats have pre-written libraries to handle things like encoding complex types and encapsulating/escaping strings/data.
2. Pick a serialization format that is well-defined and supported by both ends, that is IOS/ObjC and PHP.

   - You don't want to waste time writing new libraries to implement unsupported formats.
3. Don't store serialized data in an RDBMS, particularly MySQL.

   - Storage, access, indexing, etc all become difficult or impossible to do or do well.
   - If you're simply looking for a key-value store there are much better options than MySQL.

That said, there are two standout candidate formats:

- **JSON:** The lingua franca of the modern internet. Simple, lightweight, flexible, and damn-near everything understands it.
- **XML:** JSON's bloated uncle. Clunky, verbose, and generally a big pain in the ass; but if you want to impose typing, structure, and other such things on your data exchange format you could do worse than XML.

In the big picture what you've described sounds like the exact case for defining an REST API.

Answer (score 2):

I would typically serialise 'plain-old' objects to JSON (iOS side), post the JSON and php side, decode the JSON.  I wrote a category for dictionaries as follows ( you can use this as template for an NSArray+JSON category, should be almost identical).

NSDictionary+JSON.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDictionary (JSON)
+(id) dictionaryWithJSONdata:(NSData*)jsonData;
+(id) dictionaryWithJSON:(NSString*)jsonString;
-(NSData*) asJSONdata;
-(NSString*) asJSON;
@end
```

NSDictionary+JSON.m :

```
@implementation NSDictionary (JSON)
+ (id)dictionaryWithJSONdata:(NSData *)jsonData {
    NSError      *error;
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
    if (error) {
        MPLOG(@"*** Error encountered while deserializing JSON from server : %@", error.description);
    }
    return dic;
}

+ (id)dictionaryWithJSON:(NSString *)jsonString {
    NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithJSONdata:data];
}

- (NSData *)asJSONdata {
    NSError *error;
    NSData  *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization 
        dataWithJSONObject:self
                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                     error:&error];

    if (error) {
        MPLOG(@"*** Error while converting to JSON data : %@", error.localizedDescription);
        return nil;
    } else {
        return jsonData;
    }
}

- (NSString *)asJSON {
    NSData *jsonData = [self asJSONdata];
    if (!jsonData) {
        return @"{}";
    } else {
        return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
}

@end
```

php side :

```
   $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $ary     = json_decode($content , false); // false means as stdObj as opposed to array
```

edit : MPLOG is a personal logging framework, you should substitute for NSLog or whatever you currently use.

Answer (score 0):

A common practice is to use JSON. It's how you encode data for REST API.

But you can do whatever you like. The most important is you are able to get data.